# How to create semi circle with d3.shape that start at 9pm and ends at 6am

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-native

I am trying to create a circle with d3.shape.arc and react native art

Let's say the circle is dived to 12 so I want the circle start at 9 and end in 6 ( from 9 pm to 6 am )

this is my code:

```
const _circle = d3.shape.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .padAngle(0)
    .startAngle(5)
    .endAngle(3)
    .innerRadius(radius);
```

the circle start at 5 and go right to 4, I need it to go left ( like a clock)

[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNxmT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your scale this way:

```
var scaleHours = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 12])
  .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
```

When you specify your `arc`, you should define `startAngle` this way:

```
.startAngle(scaleHours(start))
```

For `.endAngle` you should check if your start hour more than end (9 more than 6) you should add `12` to end hour value:

```
function specifyArc(start, end) {
  return d3.arc()
    .startAngle(scaleHours(start))
    .endAngle(scaleHours(end + (start > end ? 12 : 0)))
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(radius - 10);
}
```

Check the demo below (pay attention on logs):

```js
var radius = 90;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
 .attr('width', radius * 2)
  .attr('height', radius * 2)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ', ' + radius + ')');

var scaleHours = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 12])
  .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
  
var hoursScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([0,330])
 .domain([0,11]);

var ticks = svg.selectAll('.second-tick')
  .data(d3.range(0, 12));
  
ticks.enter()
  .append('line')
  .attr('class', 'second-tick')
  .merge(ticks)
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('x2', 0)
  .attr('y1', radius)
  .attr('y2', radius - 10)
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'rotate(' + hoursScale(d) + ')';
  });
 

function specifyArc(start, end) {
 return d3.arc()
    .startAngle(scaleHours(start))
    .endAngle(scaleHours(end + (start > end ? 12 : 0)))
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(radius - 10);
}

var count = 0;

var timeframes = [
 { start: 9, end: 6 },
  { start: 6, end: 9 },
];

setInterval(() => {
 var currentTimeFrame = timeframes[count%2];
  
  console.clear();
  console.log('start: ', currentTimeFrame.start, 'end: ', currentTimeFrame.end);
  
 var arc = specifyArc(currentTimeFrame.start, currentTimeFrame.end);
  count++;
  
  svg.select('.arc').remove();
  
  svg.append("path")
   .attr('class', 'arc')
   .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", 'red');
}, 2500);
```

```css
.second-tick{
 stroke-width:3;
 fill:#000;
  stroke:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```